# Kinetic Robot hardware setup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would this be a good setup? Im mostly interested on the MB/CPU/PSU and battery

MB: [www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813186211](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813186211)

CPU: [www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115078](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115078)

PSU: [www.logicsupply.com/products/picopsu_160](http://www.logicsupply.com/products/picopsu_160)

Battery: [www.batterymart.com/p-12v-7ah-sealed-lead-acid-battery.html](http://www.batterymart.com/p-12v-7ah-sealed-lead-acid-battery.html)

Case: [www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=37_111&product_id=63#.UMlFRbT3BT5](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=37_111&product_id=63#.UMlFRbT3BT5)

Also i'll be using a Arduino/Arbotix and a motor controller for controlling motors, and servos.

Anything i should change? or look into?

Edit: I want to build a robot, that will create a map of its location using the kinetic, also i want to add 1-2 hands to it, that he can use to grab objects and open doors... Hands will use servos.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50459/kinetic-robot-hardware-setup/) by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-14**:
Please tag your question and be more specific. What do you want to achieve. Make sure you have a look at the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support).

**Comment by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on 2012-12-14**:
Updated question

**Comment by [SuperMiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3779/supermiguel/) on 2012-12-14**:
Updated question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your question is still vague. But you are missing a way to do some I/O and a motor-controller. Look in to the ros serial package and get an arduino (for instance) and a big motor controller.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0